# Draw Harvey Balls in Jupyter Notebook using Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do you draw [Harvey Balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Balls) in Jupyter Notebook using Python?

I've tried unicode Harvey Balls, but the half full circles are taller than the 3/4 full. [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Balls#Unicode)

I just need empty, quarter, half, three quarters and a full circle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but it should answer your question:

```
fig, (empty, quarter, half, three_quarters, full) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=5, figsize=(18, 3))


empty.pie([100], colors = ['white'],
          wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'black' })

quarter.pie([75, 25], colors = ['white', 'black'], startangle=90,
            wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'black' })

half.pie([50, 50], colors = ['white', 'black'], startangle=90,
         wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'black' })

three_quarters.pie([25, 75], colors = ['white', 'black'], startangle=90, 
         wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'black' })

full.pie([100], colors = ['black'],
         wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'black' } )
```